# Is it possible for C/C++ preprocessor to detect some compiler options?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, c-preprocessor

I have a function with

```
static int include[MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER*MAX_NODE_NUMBER];
static bool calculated[MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER*MAX_NODE_NUMBER]={};
```

where `MAX_NODE_NUMBER` is 200. This can be compiled only when `-mcmodel=large` is in the gcc/g++ option. The two static variables are only to cache some data so they are not so necessary. Is it possible to code like

```
#if <some condition>
static int include[MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER*MAX_NODE_NUMBER];
static bool calculated[MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER*MAX_NODE_NUMBER]={};
#endif
```

so the program can be compiled for both large memory and small memory.

Comment: Check the compiler documentation to see if it turns that option into a macro.

Comment: @Barmar [it does not](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

Comment: You should probably express this condition explicitly in your build configuration tool. It'll be much clearer and more portable to have, eg. `ENABLE_NODE_CACHE` defined whenever you set the flag `-mcmodel=large`

Comment: @YSC: [It does.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60380755/298225)

Comment: @Eric ho nice, do you know where it is documented?

Comment: @YSC: Nope, sorry, I would not be surprised if it is not documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g++` defines:

```
$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ /dev/null | grep -i model
#define __code_model_small__ 1

$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ -mcmodel=large /dev/null | grep -i model
#define __code_model_large__ 1
```

---

Alternatively:

```
$ diff <(g++ -E -dD -xc++ /dev/null) <(g++ -E -dD -xc++ -mcmodel=large /dev/null)
270c270
< #define __code_model_small__ 1
---
> #define __code_model_large__ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have command line option `-D` where you can define symbol

for example

`-DMODEL_LARGE`

then in your source file:

```
#ifdef MODEL_LARGE
static int include[MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER*MAX_NODE_NUMBER];
static bool calculated[MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER][MAX_NODE_NUMBER*MAX_NODE_NUMBER]={};
#endif
```